# MySQL delete except one

Tags: mysql, sql

I've the following database structure:

```
id   idproperty    idgbs
 1    1             136
 2    1             128       
 3    1             10
 4    1             1
 5    2             136
 6    2             128
 7    2             10
 8    2             1
 9    3             561
10    3             560
11    3             10
12    3             1
13    4             561
14    4             560
15    4             10
16    4             1
17    5             234
18    5             120
19    5             1
20    6             234
21    6             120
22    6             1
```

Here are the details:

The table refers `idproperty` with different geographic location. For example:

```
idgbs

  1 refers to United States
 10 refers to Alabama with parentid 1 (United States)
128 refers to Alabama Gulf Coast with parentid 10 (Alabama)
136 Dauphin Island with parentid 128 (Alabama Gulf Coast)
```

So, the structure is:

```
United States > Alabama > Alabama Gulf Coast > Dauphin Island
```

I want to delete all entries for idproperty EXCEPT the first with the set of idgbs 136, 128, 10, 1 i.e. leave atleast 1 property in all GBS and delete others.

Also, sometimes it is 4 level of geographic entries, sometimes it is 3 level.

Please share the logic & SQL query to delete all entries except one in every unique GBS.

GBS 1, 10, 128, 136 is one unique, so database should only contain 1 property id with these GBS.

After the query, the table would look like this:

```
id   idproperty    idgbs
 1    1             136
 2    1             128       
 3    1             10
 4    1             1
 9    3             561
10    3             560
11    3             10
12    3             1
17    5             234
18    5             120
19    5             1
```

Rephrasing the question:

I want to keep properties in every root level GBS i.e. there should be only ONE property in Dauphin Island.

Comment: So DELETE FROM YourTable where idproperty <> 1   ?

Comment: @StefanH - I think you misunderstood. I just want entries in my table with unique set of idgbs. For ex. entries with idgbs - 1, 10, 128, 136 should only be one for one property and not multiple properties.

Comment: Please show what you expect to be there after this sql is run, sort of a before and after - that will make things much more clear.

Comment: I've edited to included the output. Please check.

Comment: that output does not have all unique idgbs values.  is that accurate?

Comment: @dang With every edit you are introducing more confusion. Please be precise.

Comment: we don't want unique idgbs individually but need it in sets, for ex. 1, 10, 128, 136 idgbs (with same idproperty) should not be repeated. Another example, 1, 120, 234 idgbs should not be repeated again. Hope this clears the confusion.

Comment: @bludger - sorry for the confusion, I've rephrased the question so that it makes more sense.

Comment: Consider the rows with idgbs=1, there are rows with idproperty = (1,2,3,4,5) in the "before", and (1,3,5) in the "after". What exactly about the rows which had idproperty = (2,4) made them discard candidates, and not the others?

Comment: Let's take another example: for idgbs set = (1,10,128,136), we've following idproperty = 1, 8, 10, 11, 34, 145 i.e. these properties are in United States > Alabama > Alabama Gulf Coast > Dauphin Island. But I need only first entry i.e. idproperty 1 in this idgbs set. Is it making sense? I know its confusing.

Comment: So, the specification (1,10,128,136) is a known-value when the query is run (i.e. we aren't writing a "blanket" query to handle all cases)? (note that "known" could mean generated by programming code, but known when the query is executed)

Comment: The specification is not known. But only one condition that idgbs set will have atleast 3 level, for ex. USA > Alaska > Houston. 

We need to handle all cases.

Comment: Is there a concrete maximum depth level for the idgbs? i.e. is it a breach of data integrity if there were more than 4 levels?

Comment: Yes, there would be a maximum of 4 levels.

Comment: I think I finally "got" what you are going for. The trick was to see the rows with common idproperty values as one atomic unit, and to see that since 1 and 2 share the same idgbs set, 2 should be deleted. Is this accurate? I posted an answer which achieves that below.

Comment: @ctrahey - yes, that is absolutely right. Phew :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whew... I think I understand what you are after now. I couldn't let this one go ;-)

I had to realize that in the question, you wanted property 2 deleted, because it shared a hierarchy with property 1. Once I realized that, I got the following idea. Basically, we join to an aggregated version of self twice: the first one tells us what our "gbs hierarchy path" is, and the second one **matches any *previous* properties with the *same* hierarchy**. Rows which find that there are no "previous" properties that share their hierarchy are spared, the rest with that hierarchy are deleted. It's possible that this could be further tweaked, but I wanted to share this now. I have tested it with the data you showed, and I got the results you posted.

```
DELETE 
  each_row.*
FROM property_gbs AS each_row

JOIN ( SELECT 
         idproperty, 
         GROUP_CONCAT(idgbs ORDER BY idgbs DESC SEPARATOR "/") AS idgbs_path 
       FROM property_gbs 
       GROUP BY idproperty
     ) AS mypath 
     USING(idproperty)

LEFT JOIN ( SELECT 
              idproperty, 
              GROUP_CONCAT(idgbs ORDER BY idgbs DESC SEPARATOR "/") AS idgbs_path 
            FROM property_gbs  
            GROUP BY idproperty
          ) AS previous_property 
      ON mypath.idgbs_path = previous_property.idgbs_path 
  AND previous_property.idproperty < each_row.idproperty

WHERE previous_property.idproperty
```

Note that the last line is not a typo, we are just checking if there is a previous property with the same path. If there is, then delete the currently-evaluated row.

Cheers!

## note for clarification

The thought here is to associate every row with it's hierarchy, even if it's a row which represents somewhere in the middle of the hierarchy (such as row: {2, 1, 128} in the question). With the first join to the aggregate, each row now "knows" what it's path is (so that row would get "136/128/10/1"). We can then use that value in the second join to find other properties with the same path, but only if they have a LOWER property id. This allows us to check for the existence of a lower-ID property with the same "path", and delete any row which represents a property which *does have* such a "lower-order path-sibling".

Answer (score 2):

I'm really not sure. But try this.

```
DELETE a1 FROM table a1, table a2 
WHERE a1.id > a2.id 
AND a1.idgbs = a2.idgbs 
AND a1.idgbs <> 1
```

if you want to keep the row with the lowest id.

Answer (score 2):

This one was difficult @dang but I enjoyed the challenge.

```
;With [CTE] as (Select id ,idproperty ,idgbs ,Row_Number() Over(Partition By idgbs order by idproperty Asc) as RN From [TableGBS])
,[CTE2] as (Select * From [CTE] Where RN > 1)
,[CTE3] as (Select idproperty ,count(*) as [Count] From [CTE2] Group by idproperty)
Delete from [TableGBS] Where id in (Select a.id From [CTE] as a Left Join [CTE3] as b on a.idproperty = b.idproperty Where RN > 1 And [Count] > 2);
```

Since i dont think you can do a delete statement in sqlfiddle here are the rows it will delete showing in a select statement: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/08108/40

**Edit:** I use MySQL linked to Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio so this might not work for you

Comment: MySQL doesn't support CTEs, so this won't work for him.  Btw - you can have deletes in sqlfiddle, you just have to put them in the Schema (left) panel. After you build the new Schema, see the results by selecting from your deleted table in the query (right) panel. This is only a restriction for MySQL - other DBs can have deletes (and other dml) in the query panel.

Answer (score 0):

This technique joins the table against an aggregated version of itself, essentially matching each row in the table to the knowledge of which idproperty is the lowest for it's idgbs, and deletes the row if it does not share that idproperty (i.e. the row with the lowest idproperty, when joined to itself, will not be deleted, but the rest of the rows with that idgbs will).

```
DELETE 
  each_row.*
FROM table AS each_row
  JOIN (select MIN(idproperty), idgbs FROM table GROUP BY idgbs) as lowest_id
  USING(idgbs)
WHERE each_row.idproperty != lowest_id.idproperty;
```

Comment: Take a look at the new information, this is not quite the solution the OP is looking for

Comment: @StefanH Thanks for the heads up; I took another whack. Certainly an interesting one, eh?